# Displaying a Views Fieldset as a UL rather than a DIV

Tags: views

With [Views Fieldsets](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_fieldsets), you can display fieldsets with a 'display type' of either **div** or **fieldset**.

I'd like to set the display type as **ul**. Does anyone know how I can do this? I've tried rewriting the output but it didn't work, it rewrote the individual fieldsets rather than the parent.

Comment: I don't understand the "you can display fieldsets with a 'display type' of either or . I'd like to set the display type as .". Could you please supply a final output or your progress on this?

Comment: @Leolando Tan - Whoops; sorry! Please see my updated post. You can display fieldsets with a display type of either DIV or FIELDSET, but I need to use UL.

Comment: No problem! Oh! Looking at the the module's code, you need to override it's views field handler (views/views_fieldsets_fieldset_field_handler.inc), create your handler that extends the current handler to add your option. I think it would also require you to add some logic on how to display the fields inside your UL-type fieldset.

But looking at the module's functionality, why do you need UL when this is only meant to wrap/group fields?